# An error occurred while saving Kakao Tokens

Tags: python

[image]

[image]

I think I used the code correctly, but I'm getting a name error. How to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt declared token variable. You have to declare some value before save_tokens(KaKAO_TOKEN_FILENAME, tokens). You cant basically get variable if you declared it in a function beacause variables declared in a def function like   update_tokens are private. So line before `save_tokens(KaKAO_TOKEN_FILENAME, tokens).` set `tokens = your value`

for example:

...code...

`tokens = 'your token'`

`save_tokens(KAKAO_TOKEN_FILENAME, tokens)`

If you are beginner, and want to use api of this website, then i recommend watching some videos about ex. `api with python`. In most cases to get token, go find api documentation on this site and search for token. The token somethimes is not free or has limited uses ex. per day.